# Issue in showing error to the particular spans

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

The data is the json that i get from another page It would look similar to

data :

```
{"BusNo":["The bus no field is required."],"CompID":["The comp id field is required."],"TotalSeats":["The total seats field is required."]}
```

Here is my Script :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#driver").click(function(event) {
        var BusNo = $("#BusNo").val();
        var CompID = $("#CompID").val();
        var TotalSeats = $("#TotalSeats").val();
        var _token = $("#_token").val();
        $.post("managebus_register", {
                _token: _token,
                BusNo: BusNo,
                CompID: CompID,
                TotalSeats: TotalSeats
            },
            function(data) {
                if (data != '') {
                    var obj = JSON.parse(data);
                    $.each(obj, function(entry) {
                        var targetSelector = '';
                        if (entry == "BusNo") {
                            targetSelector = "#BusNo";
                            console.log('error in bus field');
                        }
                        if (entry == "CompID") {
                            targetSelector = "#CompID";
                            console.log('error in comp id');
                        }
                        if (entry == "TotalSeats") {
                            targetSelector = "#TotalSeats";
                            console.log('error in total seats');
                        }
                        if (targetSelector)
                            $(targetSelector).next("span.error").html(obj[entry]);
                        else {
                            $(targetSelector).next("span.error").text(' ');
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    console.log('pass');
                }
            });
    });
});
```

The condition goes inside if the   `if(data != '')`   and checks for    `targetSelector = "#BusNo";`

My problem is once the script is run it will throw the error to particular spans i.e., BusNo, CompID etc.,

And once it is filled it keeps on showing the error messages

That is, the given script

```
if (targetSelector)
    $(targetSelector).next("span.error").html(obj[entry]);
else {
    $(targetSelector).next("span.error").text(' ');
}
```

Here the else part `$(targetSelector).next("span.error").text(' ');` is not working,

What is the mistake i am doing and how can i fix this.

### Update :

I got to know

```
 $("span.error").empty();
```

Will do this

But i need to highlight the input text box with error and the error should be shown only in hover of the particular text and not in the

```
<input type="text" id="BusNo" name="BusNo"/><span class="error"></span>

<input type="text" id="CompID" name="CompID"/><span class="error"></span>
```

Comment: I also ***strongly*** recommend always using the `{}` with statements, particularly in cases like the code you highlight at the end of the question, where the `if` part doesn't have them but the `else` part does.

Comment: What is it supposed to do? You are checking if targetSelector is truthy, which it is not which means it is an empty string (or null,undefined etc) so your else statement evaluates to: `$('').next("span.error").text(' ');` which wouldn't do anything..

Comment: @JOnathanCrowe : Now   $("span.error").empty(); does the work

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for edit, I will follow your words and also use the jsbeautifier.org . Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Changes in code:

```
if (targetSelector)
   $(targetSelector).next("span.error").html(obj[entry][0]);
else {
   $(targetSelector).next("span.error").text(' ');
}
```

if you want to show error on hover:

```
$("input").hover(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    $("input").next("span.error").hide();
    $("#"+id).next("span.error").show();
})
```

Comment: Thanks, i have fixed that, Now i need to make the error apply only in the hover

Comment: The hover function should be on the on the document.ready function ?

Comment: Yes, it was working awesome, hover works, and i needed to make the error text box with red box shadow to highlight the error, how can i do it in your code pls

Comment: Add class on text box and apply css on that class

     webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 0px #ff0000;
     box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 0px #ff0000;

Comment: If i add , it will be highlighted for all the input boxes right,,,, Actually i need to highlight only that particular text box which is having error,,,,,,, How can i do this

Comment: apply according to **id** or **targetSelector** which you got.

Comment: Really sorry, i didn't understand. can you tel how, i am beginner in it. Pls help

Comment: $(targetSelector).addClass("ClassName");
or
$("#"+id).addClass("ClassName");

Comment: And i have added $("#"+id).addClass("error"); But it is reflecting to my submit button and not the input text box

Comment: please use another class instead of **error** because it use for span and also check same id is used for submit button or not. and add check condition 
if($(this).attr("type") == "text")